# A user with no email can't post a comment using Django's comments framework

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-comments

I have overrode the comments framework's `form.html` template with my own

```
{% load comments i18n %}
<form action="{% comment_form_target %}" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
    <div><input type="hidden" name="next" value="{{ request.get_full_path }}" /></div>

    {% for field in form %}
        {% if field.is_hidden %}
            <div>{{ field }}</div>
        {% else %}
            {% if field.name != "name" and field.name != "url" and field.name != "email" %}
                {% if field.errors %}{{ field.errors }}{% endif %}
                <p
                    {% if field.errors %} class="error"{% endif %}
                    {% ifequal field.name "honeypot" %} style="display:none;"{% endifequal %}
                >
                    {{ field.label_tag }}<br />
                    {{ field }}
                </p>
            {% endif %}
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}

    <p class="submit">
        <input type="submit" name="post" class="submit-post" value="{% trans "Post" %}" />
    </p>
</form>
```

It pretty much only renders the needed hidden fields (for security) and the comments field. All `comment.user` is automatically set as the current logged in user `request.user`. Here is the rendered HTML:

```
<form action="/comments/post/" method="post"><div style='display:none'><input type='hidden' name='csrfmiddlewaretoken' value='bd05094c2e3ba80e1fbec8a4237b132c' /></div>
    <div><input type="hidden" name="next" value="/doors/orders/1/" /></div>
    <div><input type="hidden" name="content_type" value="doors.order" id="id_content_type" /></div>
    <div><input type="hidden" name="object_pk" value="1" id="id_object_pk" /></div>
    <div><input type="hidden" name="timestamp" value="1333125894" id="id_timestamp" /></div>
    <div><input type="hidden" name="security_hash" value="c6791aafdd682cd8db5595681073c9a21c5fe7dd" id="id_security_hash" /></div>
    <p>
        <label for="id_comment">Comment</label><br />
        <textarea id="id_comment" rows="10" cols="40" name="comment"></textarea>
    </p>
    <p style="display:none;" >
        <label for="id_honeypot">If you enter anything in this field your comment will be treated as spam</label><br />
        <input type="text" name="honeypot" id="id_honeypot" />
    </p>
    <p class="submit">
        <input type="submit" name="post" class="submit-post" value="Post" />
    </p>
</form>
```

The problem is I noticed that if the logged in user doesn't have an email, then the comments goes to `preview.html` (which I haven't overridden). Here is the screenshot:

[image]

This is a security issue since it allows someone to change their name instead of using the logged in user's name before posting (when I list the comments, I use `comment.user.get_full_name` instead of `comment.name` so it's not an issue there, but it could still be confusing in, say, the admin page).

So my questions are:

1. How do I allow users with no email to comment?
2. How do I *not* allow the form to go to `preview.html`?
3. Is my code and design so far good?

Comment: Django's comments are far from perfect. But you can override them and use your own model and form.

Comment: But they do take care of some good security measures such as a honeypot field, double-posting, timestamped POST, security hash, etc.

Comment: You don't need to thro it all away. Just change model and form (which can be also inherited from Django's contrib).

Answer (score 3):

Well, you can use the [customization](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/contrib/comments/custom/) documentation to create a custom app that handles comments from comments framework. You should set `COMMENTS_APP = 'my_comment_app'` in your settings file and specify a `get_form()` method in your app's `__init__.py` which should return your custom form.

The custom form should be based on `contrib.comments.forms.CommentForm` and should look something like that:

```
class CustomForm(comment_forms.CommentForm):
    def __init__(*args, **kwargs):
        super(CustomFors, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields["email"].required = False
```

`preview.html` is rendered because the form contains errors (emai is required, but user doesn't have it and so it's not populated). If there are no errors - preview won't be shown.