# Django:Bind comments to any object

Tags: django

I am developing a custom commenting solution for my webapp.Can anyone tell me what's the logic behind binding comments to any model's object?I want to do something like `{% customcomment``%}`.Django comments framework already does this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/comments/

the comments framework uses Content Types and generic relations to attach a comment to any record of any model.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#module-django.contrib.contenttypes

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#id1

#### ALSO

you can extend django comments if you need to do something custom. you shouldn't need to roll your own. What specifically are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I want to allow my users to comment without providing details like email etc if they are already logged in on my webapp.Any Ideas?

Comment: See: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/comments/example/#example-of-using-the-built-in-comments-app and http://stackoverflow.com/a/3421386/884453